# STS on an MVC4 Azure Website‏

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity

I have been trying to get STS working on an Azure Website. So I created a MVC4 application using the default internet templates. I then created an STS in Azure and used the Identity and Access menu to setup federated security. I then added the [Authorize] tag to a method in my controller and the browser is redirected correctly to the STS where I can enter my LiveId account. But then I get this error

```
  An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code

[CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.]

[InvalidOperationException: ID1074: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to encrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false. ]
```

I have tried a number of things to get this to work, I think there is something small that I am missing. Has anyone come across this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by following this blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

> If you are using the Identity and Access Tools for VS2012, just go to
>   the Configuration tab and check the box “Enable Web farm ready
>   cookies”